# When to use sqlite3_blob_write/read?

Tags: c++, sql, c, sqlite

When to use sqlite3_blob_write and sqlite3_blob_read? When this functions is more useful than sqlite3_prepare_v2 + sqlite3_bind_blob?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use them when the blobs are too large for the memory available for your program, or when you need to access only a small part of a large blob.

This matters mostly in embedded applications.

Comment: That depends on the circumstances; you have to measure it.